# How to reduce memory consumption of a Qt program with CSS codes?

Tags: qt, memory, ram

I am using Qt framework to develop a software to drive a robot arm. The program is working fine but it consumes a lot of memory( 2 - 3 Gb of RAM). I have fixed a memory leak but still problem is there.

I am using many CSS codes to modify graphical aspects of widgets. I noticed that CSS code consumes a lot of available memory.

Have you ever had this problem ?
Have you any idea to reduce memory usage?

Thanks

Comment: Free dynamic objects you have created that you don't need when they are no longer needed instead of relying on the parent to delete.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to delete objects after last usage. Now i use parent to delete object so yes objects stay in memory.